# programmatically set uiimage's visibility

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I've dragged a UIImage in interface builder onto the view and selected my PNG from the dropdown, that works great but if I want to change the visibility of the uiimage according to the number of rows in this table code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

Would I have to declare the uiimage as an outlet and how would I code the visibility in the above code if the number of rows in the table was more that 1 (ie. there were rows present)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it simply based on the number of rows in the section you should just be able to do something like this:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {
      if(section == "whatever number you want to base the visibility off of")
            imageView.hidden = YES;
 }
```

Where the imageView is the UIImageView that is on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
imageView.hidden = YES;
```